# How to create a type that has many strings joined by a space

Tags: typescript

I am looking to join an unknown/unlimited number of numeric strings (with/without px). Using this code, you can only join two items. So, is there a way I can join many items using a space? If not is there a way to do it for up to 12 items easily (preferably recursive and not joining with 12 `|`'s where another item is added)?

TypeScript Version: `4.9.5`

```
export type Format = `${number}` | `${number}px`;

// Somehow create a join of `Format` separated by a space with unlimited number of values
export type Input = `${Format} `${Format}`;
```

I am looking to have all of these (and more) validate as a valid string:

```
const input: Input = '1';
const input: Input = '1 2';
const input: Input = '1 2 3';
const input: Input = '1 2 10px';
const input: Input = '10px 1 2 20px';
// And so on
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive conditional type:

```
type Last<T extends unknown[]> =
    T extends [...unknown[], infer U]
        ? U
        : never

type JoinedUnion<
    Format extends string,
    Limit extends number,
    Acc extends string[] = [Format],
> =
    Last<Acc> extends string
        ? Acc['length'] extends Limit
            ? Acc[number]
            : JoinedUnion<
                Format,
                Limit,
                [...Acc, `${Last<Acc>} ${Format}`]
            >
        : never
```

First of all `Last` is used to get the type of the last index of a tuple, this will be needed later.

Then this `JoinedUnion` type takes:

- `Format` as the string literal that each term will be
- `Limit` the maximum level of recursion allowed. This tell Typescript when to quit.
- `Acc` is the accumulated tuple of string literal types so far and is used internally to collect results and to know when to stop.

Line by line:

- `Last<Acc> extends string` solves a type error that I'm not entirely sure why it's an error. But this proves to the type checker that the last item in the tuple is a string type.
- `? Acc['length'] extends Limit` this checks if we are at the limit.
- `? Acc[number]` the limit has been reached, so index the build up tuple by `number` to get a union of all values.

Then we get to the recursion:

```
: JoinedUnion<
  Format,
  Limit,
  [...Acc, `${Last<Acc>} ${Format}`]
>
```

We get here if we are not yet at the desired length. So we call the `JoinedUnion` type again with the same format and limit, but append an entry to the tuple we are building up. That tuple is everything we previously build up (`...Acc`) then a new item that is a string literal type with the last item in the tuple plus a space and the desired format. This part is what builds the next layer.

Let's test it out:

```
type TestAB = JoinedUnion<'a' | 'b', 3>
"a" | "b" | "a a" | "a b" | "b a" | "b b" | "a a a" | "a a b" | "a b a" | "a b b" | "b a a" | "b a b" | "b b a" | "b b b"
```

I think that does what you want.

---

With your example values, it works as well:

```
export type Format = `${number}` | `${number}px`;

export type Input = JoinedUnion<Format, 12>

const inputA: Input = '1';
const inputB: Input = '1 2';
const inputC: Input = '1 2 3';
const inputD: Input = '1 2 10px';
const inputE: Input = '10px 1 2 20px';

const inputBad: Input = '10px 1 2 20pxz'; // error
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgZ2AHgCpQgD2BAdgEwSgFdcBrXAewHdcBtAXQD4oBeAKCi6nSxwKJ0AdCNIUa9BgBooAS1wAzCACcoAVQadu2gPzqt2rgC4ouCADcV7dqEhQAUpXkR8a3LMq5kBqADFKygC2cMAY2HiEUEjK8gDmUj4wsoGyoXwRRLjEgQBGKgnaAIIAxsVh-JHRcYxsUHT+QSHS7Cwc2vBIyCXFLOkCUcAxuLE+ulDddADkADZ4scAAFpMM5Rmwyamjhlx6E1m5Kprb2yaOzq7unt7HN34BwcAFt9tJKY9bz8Ii3TIABgAkAG8OihukwAL5QIENB7g35HZ5QJgfKAmMyWZTWLBgAKhWzQVAQJCFABCtTOZguHi8kzgkygAB8oJMcpMZABmZEAei5zwAejprOxsbioPi7o1QqwoADAfs8so4YyZUD5SpwWBML8ANxYzA45R48DQACSuDAxClDiclLc1OQMJCMgAjAAmZHsYqeJByc2WwomM0Wq2TZ2TXVe3A++TBkmBv0h51QV3hz3e0Ixy0AYXjwdqoeTUHZqcj0YTABFc5b80nXVBnQAGTUl9O+4MAUSriabmHrhddPdTaajGYTJLg+C7NZ7fbrA81AC9w0A)

---

Note: this resolves to a union type with over 8000 members. If you take the length 16 which gives you a member length of about 131,000, that seems to the max Typescript will allow before throwing a:

```
Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.(2590)
```

And this may make type checking slow.

Whether those tradeoffs are right for your use case is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, this looks to work so far! Very well written too!

Answer (score -3):

In your case, I think that regular expression may be a good choice:

```
// This pattern match the string that is empty or contains many number (with or without px) separated by space
const pattern = /^(\d+px|\d+)?(\s(\d+px|\d+))*$/;

class MyString {
    private str: string;
    
    constructor(str: string) {
        if (pattern.test(str)) {
            this.str = str;
        } else {
            throw new Error("Invalid string!");
        }
    }

    public toString() {
        return this.str;
    }

    // Another method...
}

const input = new MyString("10px 1 2 20px");
console.log(input.toString());

const input2 = new MyString("abc");
console.log(input2.toString()); // Invalid string error!
```